# MUI Autocomplete styling

Tags: css, material-ui, react-tsx

I have been searching for a whil but i can't find a solution. How do you apply css classes to a MUI autocomplete component in React TS. This is my Autocomplete component :

```js
                    <Autocomplete
                        freeSolo
                        value={selectedGuest}
                        onChange={(event: any, newValue: string | null | GuestModel) => {
                            console.log('onchange')
                            if(newValue){
                                //console.log("newval",newValue)
                                if(isGuestModel(newValue)){
                                    //console.log('its a guest', newValue)
                                    setSelectedGuest(newValue)
                                    setFormValue(newValue)
                                }else{
                                    setFormValue(newValue);
                                }
                            }
                        }}
                        inputValue={inputValue}
                        onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
                            console.log('onInputChange')
                            setInputValue(newInputValue)
                        }}                  
                        options={
                            uniqueAbsentGuests.sort(function (a, b) {
                                if (a.firstName < b.firstName) {
                                return -1;
                                }
                                if (a.firstName > b.firstName) {
                                return 1;
                                }
                                return 0;
                            })
                        }
                        getOptionLabel={(option: string | GuestModel) => {
                            if(typeof option === 'string'){
                                return option
                            }else{
                                return option.firstName + ' ' + option.lastName
                            }
                        }}
                        renderInput={(params) => (
                            <TextField
                                placeholder={t('firstname')}
                                {...params}
                                error={Boolean(errors?.firstName)}
                                helperText={errors?.firstName?.message}
                                {...register("firstName", { required: true })}
                            />
                        )}
                    />
```

And this is another input field in the form

```js
                    <input 
                        {...register("lastName", { required: true })} 
                        className={"form-control custom-form-control " + (errors.lastName && "is-invalid")} 
                        placeholder={t('lastname')} 
                        type="text"
                        onKeyDown ={(e) => {
                            if (e.key === "#") {
                              e.preventDefault();
                            }
                        }}
                    />
```

My css class looks like this

```css
.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #212529;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, -webkit-box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, -webkit-box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out, -webkit-box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.form-control:focus {
  color: #212529;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #e9ca85;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgba(211, 149, 11, 0.25);
          box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgba(211, 149, 11, 0.25);
}
```

I tried to create a custom Textfield which is just a styled version but it

```js
    const CustomTextField = styled(TextField)(({ theme }) => ({
        '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
          height: '38px', // Adjust height as needed
          width: '100%',
        //   backgroundColor: "red",
          padding: theme.spacing(0.5),
          '&:hover fieldset': {
            borderColor: emphasize(theme.palette.grey[400], 0),
          },
          '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
            borderWidth: 2,
            outline: 0,
          },
        },
        '& .MuiOutlinedInput-input:hover:not(:disabled):not([readonly])::file-selector-button': {
          backgroundColor: '#dde0e3',
        }
        
      }));
```

I also tried wrapping it around a themeprovider but that didn't work either.

Comment: This would go a long way if you could provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also, modify your answer to reflect, what exactly are you trying to achieve, in terms of styling.